# Adding marker points for highcharts map

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am currently working on Highcharts map. I am looking to add marker points on the world map based on the latitude and longitude data. I came across this [example](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/maps/mappoint-latlon). I am looking to replicate the lat/long example on this [map](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/maps/all-maps). If anyone could guide me in the right direction, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `proj4js` script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.6/proj4.js"></script>
```

And you should be able to add the needed lang/long points.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ncbwyke1/